# Reto de llevar un numero a 0

Tags: c++

Se debe determinar el numero de pasos minimos para que un entero N llegue a 0, siguiendo estas reglas:
1) Si N es el producto de dos numeros a y b, distintos de 1, entonces remplazar N por el max(a,b)
2) De lo contrario, remplazar N por N-1

Ejemplo: 
El numero 36 tiene 5 pasos para llegar a 0 porque:

```
      36-->6-->3-->2-->1-->0
```

Esto porque 36=6*6, N cambia al maximo (6). Luego 6=3*2, N cambia al maximo (3).
Notar que si en 36 se hubieran tomado a y b como 18 y 2, entonces el numero de pasos habria sido 6, por lo que no seria el minimo

```
   36-->18-->9-->3-->2-->1-->0
```

Entrada:
Un entero Q que sera el numero de casos a evaluar, junto a Q veces el entero N que queremos evaluar. 
Salida:
Numero mínimo de pasos para llevar cada numero a 0

Intento de solucion:
     #include 
     #include

```
 using namespace std;
 int Q, N, i, a, b;
 int main(){ 
 cin>> Q;
 for (i=0;i<Q;i++){
    cin>>N;
    int contador = 0;
    int l = N;
    for (int k=0;k<N;k++){
        if (l>0 && l == a*b){
            l=max(a,b);
            contador ++;
        }
        else if (l>0){
            l=l-1;
            contador ++;
        }
        }
        cout<<contador<<endl; 
    }
return 0;
}
```

No obstante, no supe como determinar los dos numeros a y b que multiplicados den N.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te debes enfocar en determinar divisores del número a evaluar, por ejemplo con `N = 36`:

**Los divisores son**

- 2 * 18
- 3 * 12
- 4 * 9
- 6 * 6
- ....

Ahora, la solución que te propongo es iterar y verificar para cada par de números, para obtener a y b hacemos un ciclo iniciando con 1 y por cada iteración:

1. Si `N % i == 0` entonces `a = i` y `b = N / i`(ejem 36 % 2 = 0 entonces a = 2, b = 18).
2. Luego se verifica si la diferencia entre b y a es menor o igual a cero, con esta condición encontraremos el par de números más útiles, si es así entonces pasamos al paso 3 y sino al paso 1 con `i+1` .
3. Hacemos el máximo igual a `a` y verificamos que `b` no sea igual a 1(aquí aplicamos las reglas), si `b = 0` entonces `max -= 1`, en caso contrario no hacemos nada y rompemos la iteración.

Al finalizar el nuevo valor de N sería max y también el primer número encontrado. Te dejo el código de ejemplo que he realizado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Q = 0;
int N;

int max();

int main()
{
    cout << "Numero a evaluar:  ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << N;
    do{
        N = max();      
        cout << "--->" << N;
        Q++;    
    }while(N != 0);     
    cout << "\nMinimo numero de pasos: " << Q;
    return 0;   
}

int max()
{
    int a, b;
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
    {
        if(N % i == 0)
        {
            a = i;
            b = N / i;
            if(b - a <= 0)
            {
                max = a;
                if(b == 1){
                    max -= 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

**Con N = 36 el resultado es:**

```
Numero a evaluar:  36
36--->6--->3--->2--->1--->0
Minimo numero de pasos: 5
```

De seguro debe haber una forma más sencilla, pero espero y te ayude en algo, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero tengo una observacion, el criterio que usaste para escoger los mejores a y b, que segun entiendo es seleccionar aquella pareja que aporte un numero maximo que sea menor respecto a las otras parejas (Corrigeme si me equivoco). No funciona en todos los casos, como por ejemplo con 60, la mejor solucion es 60-->12-->4-->2-->1-->0 y solo requirio 5 pasos no 6 como el codigo sugiere. De que otra forma se podria seleccionar la mejor pareja?

Comment: Así es, creo que no le realizé las pruebas necesarias, una disculpa, veré que más puedo hacer, creo que habrá que realizar un conjunto de soluciones posibles y seleccionar la más corta.